# Java Spring Profiles not working in Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, environment-variables, spring-profiles

I have a web application which i develop on Windows and after that I deploy it to Linux (Staging nad Production).

I've created 3 .properties files for each environment:

- application-dev.properties
- application-staging.properties
- application-prod.properties

I decided to implement following sollution - create enviromental variable on each machine with relevant value (dev / staging / prod) and according to this to be able to load corect .properties file.

The solution works perfectly at Windows, but I can't get it to work same way at Linux.

This is my code:

Web.xml

```
<context-param>

    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>

    <param-value>com.app.server.configuration.ConfigurableApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>

</context-param>
```

ConfigurableApplicationContextInitializer class:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;


public class ConfigurableApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        String APP_ENV = System.getenv("APP_ENV");
        context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(APP_ENV);
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", APP_ENV);

    }
}
```

ContextsConfiguration class:

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
public class ContextsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    } 


    @Value("${FTPport}")
    public String FTPport;
    @Value("${FTPserver}")
```

In Linux I've defined this variable (APP_ENV) in like million places. In .environment file, in .bash file, in setenv.sh file. Also when I do printenv - I see it there.

I tried to create simple java class - main that prints value of System.getenv("APP_ENV") and "staging" value being printed.

But in my application I allways see - dev and not staging.

The only way I got this to see staging is by adding "hard-coded" active profile to web.xml

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
    <param-value>dev</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

But I really don't want to work this way, I want it to be recognized automatically and dinamycally.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the correct place for setenv.sh is: `usr/share/tomcat7/bin`
And I had there an old file with "dev" value :)
So after fixing this file - it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons might be is that your tomcat is running under a different user, so you might need to set the environment variable for *that* user which runs tomcat.

You can also set required environment variables for tomcat in `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` file

Comment: Hey Zilvinas - thanks for your answer. I run everything from my user - I'm also that one installed Tomcat. The value exists in setenv.sh

Comment: This is what I have in setenv.sh:                                                              export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms512m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
export APP_ENV = "staging"                              Maybe this is incorrect way?

Comment: @Vika That should do I think